# creating shadow like border in titanium

Tags: textbox, titanium-mobile

[image]

i want to create a textfield like above, which has shadow like border and on focus it has to highlight with orange color .Please can anybody help me how to do this i am new to titanium

i have used below code for textfield,i am currently getting blackborder

```
var txt = Titanium.UI.createTextField({

color : '#006881',
borderStyle :       Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
borderColor:'#000000',
borderRadius:5,
borderWidth:2,
top : 10,
left : 10,
right : 10,
font : txtfont_text,

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

create a view add the Textfield inside 
(width:Ti.UI.FILL,height:Ti.UI.FILL,top:2)

In textfield.addEventListenr('focus') change the backgroundColor of the view and in 'blur' listener update the backgroundColor again.